# Layout Messing Up When I Add Text

Tags: html

Well, I have a problem. I have my layout exactly as I want it, but when I add text in, the layout changes. It's kind of hard to explain, so I'm going to show pictures.

### Layout Before Text:

[image]

### Layout After Text:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated

```css
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.header {
    color: #AEC6CF;
    font-family: gabriola;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-size: 50px;
 position: relative;
}


/* ID */

#row1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
}

#row2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5%;
}

#row3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}

#row4 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5%;
}

#row5 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 9.7%;
}

#column1 {
 border-bottom: 3px solid black;
 border-right: 3px solid black;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: -0.25%;
}

#column2 {
 border-bottom: 3px solid black;
 border-left: 3px solid black;
 width: 79%;
 height: 100%;
 right: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: -0.25%;
}


/* Misc. */

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}

.left {
    text-align: left;
}

.clearfix  {
 float: clear;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <div id="row1">
    <div id="column1" class="clearfix">
    </div>
    
             <div id="column2" class="clearfix">
                 <h1 class="header center">See The Problem?</h1>
             </div>
   </div>

   <div id="row2">
    <div id="column1" class="clearfix">
    </div>

    <div id="column2" class="clearfix">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="row3">
    <span id="column1" class="clearfix">
    </span>

    <span id="column2" class="clearfix">
    </span>
   </div>

   <div id="row4">
    <span id="column1" class="clearfix">
    </span>

    <span id="column2" class="clearfix">
    </span>
   </div>

   <div id="row5">
    <div id="column1" class="clearfix" style="border-bottom: 0px;">   
                </div>
                
                <div id="column2" class="clearfix" style="border-bottom: 0px;">
    </div>
   </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't you make use of Tables in HTML??

Comment: You can, but tables aren't meant to be used for layouts. So generally speaking you shouldn't use them for that.